# How can I use POST from requests module to login to Github?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, github, python-requests

I have tried logging into GitHub using the following code:

```
url = 'https://github.com/login'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
          'login':'username',
          'password':'password',
          'authenticity_token':'Token that keeps changing',
          'commit':'Sign in',
          'utf8':'%E2%9C%93'
}

res = requests.post(url)
print(res.text)
```

Now, `res.text` prints the code of login page. I understand that it maybe because the token keeps changing continuously. I have also tried setting the URL to `https://github.com/session` but that does not work either.

Can anyone tell me a way to generate the token. I am looking for a way to login without using the API. I had asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533741/where-can-i-use-the-post-method-without-any-api-in-real-life) where I mentioned that I was unable to login. One comment said that I am not doing it right and it is possible to login just by using the requests module without the help of Github API.

ME:

> So, can I log in to Facebook or Github using the POST method? I have tried that and it did not work.

THE USER:

> Well, presumably you did something wrong

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong?

After the suggestion about using sessions, I have updated my code:

```
s = requests.Session()
headers = {Same as above}

s.put('https://github.com/session', headers=headers)    
r = s.get('https://github.com/')

print(r.text)
```

I still can't get past the login page.

Comment: why aren't you using the API? https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: I want to do it without the API. It is not only about logging into GitHub though. I would be happy with anything practical where I can use the post method of requests module to do something on a website (other than websites like httpbin).

Answer (score 2):

I think you get back to the login page because you are redirected and since your code doesn't send back your cookies, you can't have a session.

You are looking for session persistance, `requests` provides it :

> Session Objects The Session object allows you to persist certain
>   parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all
>   requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3's
>   connection pooling. So if you're making several requests to the same
>   host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result
>   in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent
>   connection).

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')

print(r.text)
# '{"cookies": {"sessioncookie": "123456789"}}'
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: I still can't get past the login page.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in post method the request parameters should be in request body, not in header.So the login data should be in data parameter.

For github, authenticity token is present in value attribute of an input tag which is extracted using BeautifulSoup library.

This code works fine

```
import requests
from getpass import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
'commit': 'Sign in',
'utf8': '%E2%9C%93',
'login': input('Username: '),
'password': getpass()
}
url = 'https://github.com/session'
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
login_data['authenticity_token'] = soup.find(
'input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']
response = session.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
response = session.get('https://github.com', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly

```
headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    'commit': 'Sign in',
    'utf8': '%E2%9C%93',
    'login': 'your-username',
    'password': 'your-password'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
 url = "https://github.com/session"
 r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
 login_data['authenticity_token'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']

 r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the PyGitHub API to perform common git tasks.
Check the link below:
https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub